# What is Earth's current true anomaly from j2000?

Tags: orbital-motion, astronomy

I enjoy amateur astronomical calculations. I calculate earth true anomaly and noticed a bug in my software just as earth passing through j2000 point and instead of going to 0 degrees it subtracting from 360.

But I checked wolfram alpha and with in a few days went from like 359 degrees now reports 179 degrees. If J2000 was 358 degrees or so, it should be very close to that or 0 degrees approx today, January 3, 2019?

Comment: Would [astronomy.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's really a question of precise mathematical notation for elliptical orbit.

Comment: It probably may be a good or better place, they probably use it to determine exact position of stars for viewing.

Comment: I dont know how to easily move question?

Comment: But it should be answerable here. If true anomaly is angle from earth to perhelion side of major axis of orbits ellipse, then I'm correct in that earth passes through 0 degrees at roughly January 3. I remember also wolfram reported correctly 180 around august, earth aphelion. So wolfram appears to be in error as well haha.

Comment: Do you mean that `PlanetData["Earth", "TrueAnomaly"]` is calculating the wrong angle? Then this question should be raised on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: This was just through the wolfram alpha website. My code was in client js and I'm not really familiar with mayhematica or how wolfram arrives at that result. But I could see that perhaps it could be really an issue with mathematica.

Comment: But the real question is the value of true anomaly. I've asked on astronomy also. I really think it's value is erroneous.

Comment: I guess the question is basically when was earths 2019 perhelion? We either are just short of it or just passed it, then wolfram is off by positive or negative 180 degrees?

Comment: That value from WolframAlpha is definitely a bug. I've replicated your result and submitted a bug report. Wolfram Alpha is a very large collection of software; it has bugs. No large collection of software is bug-free, even if developed under the most rigorous conditions (which WA is not). The Space Shuttle flight software was developed under such conditions (at great expense), and it was estimated have at most five unreported and unfixed bugs in a code base of over 400000 lines of code. I don't know the rigor to which WA is developed, but it's not CMMI level 5. That's ridiculously expensive.

Comment: The thing to do when confronted with an obvious bug like this is to submit a bug report. You don't need to confirm with us that the result is erroneous.

Comment: I'm not a phd or professional of orbital mechanics, so I wasn't sure, or if I'm just wrong. That said if is a bug, I do understand how this can happen. We both realized a very similar issue that comes up with trigonometric functions in applied math, an error of 180 degrees and multiples of it. I was quite aware of this, and did put extra effort to avoid, and yet on January 3, there it is. It shows just how difficult bugs are to avoid. But I understand we aren't computers. Our ability to make mistakes are a virtue. Even this is perhaps a example of some querky symmetry group.

Comment: Maybe how we discover such subtle abstract things. That said its interesting about the space shuttle, I love space shuttle trivia from ome 1 not necessary to it being one of the most complicated devices made by humans. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an almanac for earth perhelion up to 2100. 2019 perhelion occurred at roughly 5:00 January 3,2019. Thus the angle now of true anomaly is some extent past 0 degrees. And wolfram alpha is wrong by negative 180 degrees. By Wikipedia and other standard definitions of mean anomaly which have persisted sense Kepler's time.

While there does appear to be some deviation among sources, I find some in different time zone, on apparently from ny times reporting it occurred at a little after midnight January 3, 2019 which seems to correspond with  a 5 am GMT time.